# Chromatic recurrence

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

1) How do you prove the Chromatic recurrence theorem: $$χ(G;k)=χ(G−e;k)−χ(G·e;k)$$

I'm thinking by induction, but then you would have to assume something about the type of graph G...surely it can't be done any other way?

2) (See below - please ignore my numbering)! Let this graph be G.

Find an explicit formula for $χ(G;t)$.

[image]

My answer: $χ(G;k) = k(k-1)(k-2)^2(k-3)^2$

Is this correct? Or is this not an 'explicit' formula?

Comment: I've never seen this notation.  Can you please state what the $t$ stands for in $\chi(G;t)$ ?

Comment: @manuellafond Sorry, it should be a k there.

Comment: I was asking about the notation.  I did found out it's the number of proper $k$-colorings right here : http://www.sfu.ca/~mdevos/notes/graph/445_colouring0.pdf.  There's also a 3-line proof of (1) in Proposition 6.11.  Theorem 6.13 might might also help you, though it requires a summation over all $2^{|E||}$ subsets of edges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 2) I would choose to use a different formulation of 1); Addition-Identification:
$$P(H-e,x) = P(H,x) + P(H/e,x)$$
Note that this is the breakdown used in the proof of 1) by Andreas. It is usually better to use this to find the polynomial when the graph has a vertex joined to nearly all other vertices.

If we let $H$ be the graph with the two vertices of valency 4 joined by an edge then we can use the following equation:
  $$P(G,x) = P(K_2 +(2K_2),x) + P(K_1+(2K_2),x)$$

Now in both of these graphs there is a vertex joined to all others so we can use Total Adjacency which I explained in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/761362/chromatic-polynomial-of-a-graph-might-take-a-while/762869#762869): since $2K_2$ is two trees we must have $P(2K_2,x) = x^2(x-1)^2$ and thus $P(K_1+(2K_2),x) = x P(2K_2,x-1) = x(x-1)^2(x-2)^2$ and finally 
$$P(K_2+(2K_2),x) = P(K_1+(K_1+2K_2),x) = x(x-1)(x-2)^2(x-3)^2$$

Putting these two together we get:

$$P(G,x) = x(x-1)(x-2)^2(x-3)^2 + x(x-1)^2(x-2)^2 \\
        = x(x-1)(x-2)^2(x^2-6x+9 + x-1) \\
        = x(x-1)(x-2)^2(x^2-5x+8)  $$

Note that this agrees with the numbers given by Andreas.

Answer (score 4):

For (1), let $u$ and $v$ be the endpoints of the edge $e$, and notice that the proper $t$-colorings of $G-e$ are of two sorts: those that give $u$ and $v$ the same color, and those that don't. A coloring of the first sort, with the same color for $u$ and $v$, amounts to a proper coloring of what I call $G/e$ and you call $G\cdot e$, the graph obtained from $G$ by identifying the two vertices $u$ and $v$ and removing $e$ (which would otherwise be a loop at the identified vertex).  On the other hand, a coloring of the second sort amounts to a proper coloring of $G$, i.e., it remains proper when you restore the edge $e$ to $G-e$ and thereby obtain the original $G$.  Thus, the number of proper $t$-colorings of $G-e$ is the sum of the number of proper $t$-colorings of $G/e$ and the number of proper $t$-colorings of $G$.  That (after transposing one term) is the equation in (1).

As for (2), your formula, in which $k$ was presumably intended to be $t$, can't be right, because it vanishes when $k$ (or $t$) is $3$, whereas the graph does have a proper $3$-coloring: Use color $3$ at the two vertices so labeled in your picture, color $1$ at the leftmost and rightmost vertices, and color $2$ at the top and bottom vertices.

Comment: Ok, so what should the explicit formula look like? I have no idea

Comment: One approach to an explicit formula: Use the recurrence theorem to reduce the problem to finding the chromatic polynomials of some graphs with fewer edges (9 instead of 10). Repeat to get fewer edges yet. Continue thus, until you have graphs with no edges. A graph with no edges and n points obviously has chromatic polynomial $t^n$. Another approach might be to use the fact that $\chi(G,t)$ is a monic polynomial of degree 6, so it's determined by its values for 6 values of $t$. For $t=0,1,2$ the value is clearly 0, and for $t=3$ it's 12; only 2 to go.